# How to pull table record in asp.net mvc 5 using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, bootstrap-4

I have modal form, but i am struggling to pull the table record from the database once a user first check radio button(EmailAddress) and puts a correct email from the Textbox, as soon click Next button it must prompt following columns Name, EmailAddress, LoginID, SSID and Institution. Below is my logic and need some help to put it back with data.

```
 <pre> public class eNtsaRegPeopleLists
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Key]
            public int LoginID { get; set; }
            public string Name {get;set;}
            public string SISID { get; set; }
            public string EmailAddress {get;set;}
            public string Role { get; set; } // ignore this one from the View
            public DateTime LastActivity { get; set; } // ignore this one from the View
            public decimal TotalActivity { get; set; } // ignore this one from the View
            public string Institution { get; set; }
        }

    <div class="form-group row">
                                     <div class="col-sm-4">
                                         <input type="radio" id="EmailAddress" name="choose" />
                                         <label for="EmailAddress" class="col-form-label">EmailAddress</label>
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="col-sm-3">
                                         <input type="radio" id="LoginID" name="choose" />
                                         <label for="LoginID" class="col-form-label">LoginID</label>
                                     </div>
    
                                     <div class="col-sm-3">
                                         <input type="radio" id="SIS_ID" name="choose"/>
                                         <label for="SIS_ID" class="col-form-label">SIS_ID</label>
                                     </div>
    
                                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                                         @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.eNtsaAdmin.eNtsaTextAreaDisc, new { @class = "form-control", style = "font-size: medium; font-weight: bold; width:450px", id= "eNtsaTextAreaDisc" })
    
                                     </div>
                                     <hr />
    
    
                                 </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" id="btnNext">
                                       Next
                                   </button>
                               </div>
 @foreach(var data in Model.regPeopleLists)
                                        {
                                            
                                        }
    <div class="modal-body">
                                          <table class="table table-bordered">
                                              <thead>
                                                  <tr>
                                                      <th>Name</th>
                                                      <th>EmailAddress</th>
                                                      <th>LoginID</th>
                                                      <th>SISID</th>
    
                                                  </tr>
                                              </thead>
                                          </table>
                                      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Fire when radio button clicked
                $("#LoginID, #SIS_ID").bind("change", function () {
                    checkdata();
                });
    
                // Fire when we enter anything in the textbox
                $("#eNtsaTextAreaDisc").bind("input", function () {
                    checkdata();
                });
            });
    
            //here we check both radio button clicked and textbox filled with some information
            function checkdata() {
                if (($("#LoginID").prop("checked") || $("#SIS_ID").prop("checked")) && $("#eNtsaTextAreaDisc").val().length > 0) {
                    $("#btnNext").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
                else {
                    $("#btnNext").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: where is `exampleModalCenter` in your code ?

Comment: button "data-target", look in between Next and Close button class

Comment: no the div with id `exampleModalCenter`  which will get called when you clicked on `next` button.

Comment: @Swati show me which line?

Comment: I didn't find any thing like this `<div id="exampleModalCenter "..>` in your code provided .

Comment: i think is not included to the code, could be reason to it.